# Better way than CTE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I've written a simple query, but I feel there should be a better way to do it. I'm essentially looking for a way to clean up this code to make it neater and more usable in the future. I will be using this in a few ssrs reports.

```
DECLARE @Month int = MONTH(GETDATE());
DECLARE @Year int = YEAR(GETDATE());
DECLARE @ThisMth DATE = DATEFROMPARTS(@Year,@Month,1);
DECLARE @BegYear DATE = DATEFROMPARTS(@Year, 7,1);

--EMPLOYEES
With EmpCount AS  
(
    SELECT  
        COUNT(DISTINCT(Employee)) As 'DistinctEmployees', PRCo 
    FROM 
        PREA 
    WHERE 
        Mth = @ThisMth 
    GROUP BY 
        PRCo),
TotalEmp AS  
(
    SELECT  
        COUNT(DISTINCT(Employee)) As 'TotalDistinctEmployees', PRCo 
    FROM 
        PREA 
    WHERE 
        Mth >= @BegYear 
    GROUP BY 
        PRCo),
Earnings AS
(
     SELECT 
         SUM(Amount) AS Earnings, PRCo 
     FROM 
         PREA 
     WHERE 
         Mth = @ThisMth AND EDLType = 'E' 
     GROUP BY 
         PRCo),
TotalEarnings AS 
(
     SELECT 
         SUM(Amount) as TotalEarnings, PRCo 
     FROM 
         PREA 
     WHERE 
         Mth >= @BegYear and EDLType = 'E' 
     GROUP BY 
         PRCo),
Deductions AS 
(
     SELECT 
         SUM(Amount) AS Deduction, PRCo 
     FROM 
         PREA 
     WHERE 
         Mth = @ThisMth AND EDLType = 'D' 
     GROUP BY PRCo),
TotalDeduction AS 
(
     SELECT 
         SUM(Amount) as TotalDed, PRCo 
     FROM 
         PREA 
     WHERE 
         Mth >= @BegYear AND EDLType = 'D' 
     GROUP BY 
         PRCo),
Liabilities AS 
(
    SELECT 
        SUM(Amount) AS Liab, PRCo 
    FROM 
        PREA 
    WHERE 
        Mth = @ThisMth AND EDLType = 'L' 
    GROUP BY
       PRCo),
TotalLiabilities AS 
(
    SELECT 
        SUM(Amount) as TotalLiab, PRCo 
    FROM 
        PREA 
    WHERE 
        Mth >= @BegYear AND EDLType = 'L' 
    GROUP BY 
        PRCo)
SELECT 
    a.PRCo, ec.DistinctEmployees, tem.TotalDistinctEmployees, 
    e.Earnings, te.TotalEarnings, d.Deduction, td.TotalDed, 
    l.Liab, tl.TotalLiab, te.TotalEarnings + tl.TotalLiab AS TotalCost
FROM 
    PREA a
INNER JOIN 
    EmpCount ec ON ec.PRCo = a.PRCo
INNER JOIN 
    Earnings e ON e.PRCo = a.PRCo
INNER JOIN 
    TotalEarnings te ON te.PRCo = a.PRCo
INNER JOIN 
    TotalEmp tem ON tem.PRCo = a.PRCo
INNER JOIN 
    Deductions d ON d.PRCo = a.PRCo
INNER JOIN 
    TotalDeduction td ON td.PRCo = a.PRCo
INNER JOIN 
    Liabilities l ON l.PRCo = a.PRCo
INNER JOIN 
    TotalLiabilities tl ON tl.PRCo =a.PRCo
WHERE 
    Mth = @ThisMth AND EDLType = 'E'
GROUP BY 
    a.PRCo, ec.DistinctEmployees,e.Earnings, te.TotalEarnings, 
    tem.TotalDistinctEmployees, d.Deduction, td.TotalDed, l.Liab, tl.TotalLiab
```

Comment: One way of evaluating a query is to look at the _execution plan_. That will show you what the query optimizer has done to help or hurt. Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. `tsql` doesn't specify either. And use aliases throughout, i.e. where does `Mth` come from in the last `WHERE` clause?

Comment: CASE statements as well as using the OVER (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) clause _might_ help you to avoid doing all the CTE queries - but whether it'll actually perform better in your situation requires testing.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30624475/multi-column-conditional-aggregation

Comment: Thank you for the replies, I have amended the tags. Thank you.

I will keep that in mind for future (using aliases). I'm not really after performance, more so a better way to do it. I know that my version works as a hack, but I would like to know a better way to write it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
    SELECT PRCo
          ,COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN  Mth = @ThisMth  THEN Employee ELSE NULL END )) As 'DistinctEmployees'
          ,COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN  Mth >= @BegYear  THEN Employee ELSE NULL END )) As 'TotalDistinctEmployees'
          ,SUM(CASE WHEN Mth = @ThisMth AND EDLType = 'E' THEN  Amount ELSE 0 END ) AS Earnings
          ,SUM(CASE WHEN Mth >= @BegYear and EDLType = 'E' THEN  Amount ELSE 0 END) AS TotalEarnings
          ,SUM(CASE WHEN Mth = @ThisMth AND EDLType = 'D' THEN  Amount ELSE 0 END ) AS Deduction
          ,SUM(CASE WHEN Mth >= @BegYear and EDLType = 'D' THEN  Amount ELSE 0 END ) AS TotalDed
          ,SUM(CASE WHEN Mth = @ThisMth AND EDLType = 'L'  THEN  Amount ELSE 0 END ) AS Liab
          ,SUM(CASE WHEN Mth >= @BegYear and EDLType = 'L'  THEN  Amount ELSE 0 END ) AS TotalLiab
          ,SUM(CASE WHEN Mth >= @BegYear and EDLType like '[EL]' THEN  Amount ELSE 0 END) AS TotalCost
    FROM PREA AS p
    GROUP BY PRCo
```

Comment: Thank you, Nolan, this worked and it allows for cases where there is no data.